# batch mysql does not show strings

Tags: mysql, batch-file

ust experimenting with mysql and batch file (call me nostalgic :-) )

```
echo SELECT some_field FROM some_table WHERE some_field like '%needle%' \G > command.sql
mysql -s -q -h %svr% --user=%user% --password=%pass%  %database% < command.sql
```

This command works perfect for numerical results, but for string results, it is just blank. even if I list the complete table result, it shows all the numerical values, but the field that has strings it is just blank.

example 2 rows have "jane doe", and mysql displays

```
************* 1. row ***********************
Name:
************* 2. row ***********************
Name:
```

but age works

```
************* 1. row ***********************
Age: 33
************* 2. row ***********************
Age: 105
```

Is there a setting I can use?

ps this is obvious a simplified version of what I am working with. Most my tables have over 40-50 fields. I can do all this in pasca/qb64/VB/php etc. Just wanting to expand some batch skills

Comment: one note, under mysql command line - everything works well, I just want to do it under batch

Comment: [Escape](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html) `%` sign in a batch script by doubling them as follows: `echo SELECT some_field FROM some_table WHERE some_field like '%%needle%%' \G > command.sql`. Add `type command.sql` to see what happens.

Comment: THAT WORKED! Once you showed me that, I realized that the "%" is a wildcard for DOS so I am sure it tried to interpret "needle" as a set variable, the 2nd "%" made it viable Thank you!